# Actionscript error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When I try to compile this Actionscript code code with 'as3compile.exe', I get this error :

**Code:**

```
package
{    

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var myvct:uint = 0;
        public function Start():void
        {
            myvct = new Vector.<uint>();

        }

        public function Main():void
        {
            Start();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
error: syntax error, unexpected '<'
```

Can anyone please tell me whats is wrong here?

Comment: are you sure it'a all content? It compiles fine to me. Besides you define your variable as vector when you want to assign vector to it - `private var myvct:Vector.<uint>;`

Comment: It worked compiled smoothly with : Adobe’s Flex SDK's mxmlc.exe.

Comment: @Dev.K. you were likely targeting wrong (older) Flash Player version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Adobe’s Flex SDK's mxmlc.exe to compile the same code. It worked smoothly.